# Migrate users from database to another on Django

Tags: django, database, web, migration, django-2.0

I already have an existing website running and want to transfer just the users (usernames, passwords and emails) to another database for a separate Django website as I am rebuilding it.

Comment: It would be useful to know the type of database/s you are using on the old and new platform

Comment: Do you use Django for both websites?

Comment: Yes so the current website is still using dbsqlite 3 and I will be migrating to a MySQL database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure both databases in your django configuration file. select the user data from one database and then put the records in the other.

[Multiple Databases in Django.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/)

[Moving an object from one database to another](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#moving-an-object-from-one-database-to-another)

Comment: The thing is I don't want to be using dbsqlite 3 anymore as it is just a development server and will still like to keep the users I have now

is there not a way to do something like .  python manage.py dumpdata users > users.json

Comment: But you don't need use only sqlite in your config. the database backend can be a PostgreSQL, so you can select the user data usin **users = get_user_model().object.using('default').all()** and then use **get_user_model().object.using('otherdb').bulk_create(users)**

is Not what you're looking for?

Comment: I dont quite understand what your trying to say, so what I do is I set up django to use both databases then run those commands in the django python shell then the users will exist on that databse

Comment: see the second link